# Ruby on Rails tutorial, 5.3.4 exercise, How do I use the assert_equal method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

In the exercise, a test is written for the full_title helper and one has to fill in code. Here is the test

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title,         FILL_IN
    assert_equal full_title("Help"), FILL_IN
  end
end
```

How does the assert_equal method work here? I'm confused as to what I should put in for the expected and actual.

Answer (score 0):

`expected` is the value represents the proper behavior, and `actual` is the what actually gets returned. If `full_title` is the thing that you're testing, then it should be the `actual` parameter and the output that you what the method to have should be the `expected` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test with the assertion using this format:

```
assert_equal( expected, actual, [msg] )
```

So you want to test that the expected value "full_title" in this case will equal the actual value. The last part `[msg]` is an optional message parameter you can include to clarify your feedback if your test fails. The `FILL_IN` part is where you insert your actual value.  So if `full_title` has a value of `"Welcome To My Site"`, you would test that value by writing an assertion like:

```
assert_equal full_title, "Welcome To My Site"
```

and if the value of `full_title("Help")` should be `"Welcome To My Site | Help"`
then you would test it like so:

```
assert_equal full_title, "Welcome To My Site | Help"
```

and if you can include the optional message parameter, to make your failure message a bit clearer:

```
assert_equal full_title, "Welcome To My Site | Help", "This was not the correct title"
```

and in the event that you're test fails, that message will show up as part of your logs.

There is a Rails guide which goes into more details on how to use assertions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I am also going through the tutorial and noticed a slight difference from MisterCal's answer in how to write the test.

`assert_equal( expected, actual, [msg] )`
is the right format but his example uses the full_title method call as the expected when that is the actual result that you are getting.

Below the string is the expected and the helper method call is the actual value you get when calling it. Don't forget to call the method with an argument otherwise you will trigger the default parameter you set earlier

`assert_equal "Welcome To My Site | Help", full_title("Help"), "This was not the correct title"`